# How to add query vars with paginated URLs?

Tags: php, mysql

How I can insert some custom url parameters to pagination links? the code below display like

`page.php?cpage=2`

But I would like to add a parameter `category` with value `fruit`. So, the final url will look like below.

`page.php?cpage=2&category=fruits`

and so on..

`page.php?cpage=2&category=fruits&color=red&size=small`

Where and how do I insert the code to make the above happen?

```
  echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'total' => ceil($total / $items_per_page),
    'current' => $page
  ));
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use the `add_args` parameter to add an array of query string arguments to [pagination links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links):

```
  echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'total' => ceil($total / $items_per_page),
    'current' => $page,
    'add_args' => array(
        'category' => 'fruit',
        'color' => 'red'
    )
  ));
```